# Show my most recently sent message on top in Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, messages

In Mac Mail I'd like to see the most recently sent message - whether it is my reply or the senders email - on top in list preview and also in the detailed view window. This doesn't seem to be possible. In list view even if I were the last person to write, my message is only visible if I expand all messages. In detail view the top message which automatically loads is the last message by the sender and I have to scroll up to see my sent message even if it is newer.

I wonder how I can fix this. Thanks.

Using Mac Mail 9.3, OSX El Cap.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the closest you'll get to this is to ensure you expand all conversations. However, there are preferences that may impact on the expansion.

So, let's try the following:

- In Mail, go to Mail > Preferences
- Click on the Viewing tab
- Ensure the *Include related messages* checkbox is ticked
- Ensure the *Show most recent messages* at the top checkbox is ticked
- Exit Preferences
- Now within Mail go to your Inbox
- Ensure the filter at top left is sorted **by date** and that *Newest Message on Top* is ticked
- Go to the View menu and ensure that *Organise by Conversation* is ticked
- Go to the View menu and select Expand All Conversations (Note: This won't place a tick there, it just expands them)

After doing the above you should get something close to what you want.